# Derive a trait by delegating to a struct member which implements that trait

Tags: rust, macros, traits

Consider the following struct:

```
struct SectoredStream<T> {
    sector_sz: usize,
    inner: T,
}
```

When `T` implements `Read` I can implement `Read` for `SectoredStream<T>` as follows:

```
impl<T: Read> Read for SectoredStream<T> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        self.inner.read(buf)
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, but in general I may want to implement a complex trait by delegating all of the trait methods to one of the members of my struct which implements that trait. It seems clear that this type of boilerplate code could be generated by a macro, and I can see how to do it for a particular trait using a declarative macro. I believe the general case will require a procedural macro, but I doubt this is a unique problem. So, is there already a crate which implements this macro?

Comment: Please note that questions seeking recommendations for software libraries are generally not a good format for stackoverflow, as they are likely to lead to opinion-based answers.
That being said, the [Ambassador](https://github.com/hobofan/ambassador) crate looks like something that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Generally, this is impossible, as proc macros are stateless. However, there are various hacks (that may not work in the future) to save state, and crates that implement them, as @SirDarius mentioned.

Comment: There is also the [delegate](https://crates.io/crates/delegate) crate. It works a lot more simply and will still require the function signatures each time, but its something that can help with consistency.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It looks like the ambassador crate is exactly what I had in mind. @ChayimFriedman I would be interested in learning why this crate must be utilizing "hacks". In general, because Rust favors composition over inheritance, it would make sense for the language team to support this kind of code generation. If not through procedural macros, then how?

Comment: When you really need trait delegation, you should delegate all functions, in order that you don't fall back to slow defaults implementations while the delegate provides high performance implementations. Finally ask yourself why you need delegation at all? Mostly you can change your API to not depend on `Read` but on some indirection like `AsMut<Read>` or an own `AsRead` trait, that automatically implements for all `impl<T: Read> AsRead for T {}` and your `SectoredStream` also implements for `R: Read`. Maybe delegation is just a solution to bad API design.